character size change in NLA
I want to mix motions and its not working properly.
I have a character in my Blender file and when I import more than one action in the NLA Editor the second motion that was working fine in action editor, now changes size and scale.
From frame 0 to 100 I have normal character (first motion) and then from frame 101 I have a giant character at nowhere.
Motions are made in I clone, I work in Blender 4.2.
